# Is there a way to pass selected drop-down value to other controller in angular js?

Tags: drop-down-menu, angularjs-directive

i have a drop-down in the main controller. And i want to pass the selected value to another directive which builds charts.
In main.html i have:

```
    <select class="form-control"  ng-options="s as s.Name for s in Data" 
     ng-model="SelectedDataoption"  ng-change="DataSelected()" ></select> 

<build-chart selected={{selectedvalue}}></build-chart>
```

in main.js

```
$scope.DataSelected=function(){
$scope.selectedvalue=$scope.SelectedDataoption.Name};
```

but i get empty value in build-chart controller.

Comment: Maybe your ng-options is not well populated, how is the content of your Data variable?

Comment: i can get the values in main.. nothing wrong with ng-options

Comment: That means I'm missing something, is the same controller for everything?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put the value in $rootScope (in common with all the controllers by definition). But I'm not sure it is the best solution.

Comment: i tried that, it doest capture when the value is changed tho

Comment: So you just have to add the default value in $rootScope.selected and it's good right? I don't see any other solutions for passing values through several controllers.